# What is the process to remove an in-ground pool?

Tags: pool

- What are the steps involved for removing an in-ground ***plaster*** pool and is this something that can be done with a few buddies?

(Backyard single family home type pool; see [Massive Pool Leak](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/79914/massive-pool-leak) for details and pictures).

Comment: If it's a plaster pool (as indicated by the estimate in the linked question) you basically need to jack hammer off the top 12-18 inches, jack hammer some drainage holes into the bottom and fill the remainder.  The shell will always remain.  If you don't want to deal with soil setting long issues for the first 5-8 years use sand for the bottom up to 24" from the top and use dirt for the top 24".  If it's a vinyl liner or fiberglass pool the answer is different.

Comment: Just an FYI, I have a gunite pool and when the bank repo-ed the house they had a new vinyl liner installed. It might be far cheaper than ripping the pool out.

Comment: @machavity: the pool has brand new cracks each month, after the rain, as the ground shifts. Does the the vinyl liner solve this issue ?

Comment: I can't say that with 100% certainty, but the liner should reduce, if not remove, the leaks. Depends a great deal how much shifting we're  talking about